# Is there a way to install a dependency when need it? Or dynamically

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a vscode extension. Some of the dependencies will not be needed in every situation.

So I want to install some of the dependencies only when the user needs them. How to do this?

Comment: you want VSC to download some node modules in your extension when needed, you bundle all needed node modules when you publish the extension

Comment: VSCode extensions are Node.js applications. In general, whatever you can/cannot do on Node.js (like optional dependencies), is also what you can/cannot do there (exceptions are rare).